# ConfigurationException filename is null

Tags: c#, configuration

From time-to-time, my users will get a ConfigurationException from a corrupt user.config file. I would like to automatically rest or delete the user.config so that the user can start over. I was hoping to obtain the filename (which has some hash in it), but the filename is null in the exception. How can I retrieve the correct configuration file so I can delete it?

Some hints found here - http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/601193-how-do-i-restore-corrupted-user-config-file - but doesn't work because the filename is null.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you must add a reference to System.Configuration and catch ConfigurationErrorsException instead. Look in the inner exception for the filename.